# Notepad++ Regex find 2nd set of characters (same characters)

Tags: regex, notepad++

assume i have the following text

```
<p>My name is CK, <br/> i stay in US. <br/> I'm 24 years old.</p>
```

how can i just only find the 2nd `<br/>` (after US.) in this line of text using notepad++ regex find & replace

so far the only things i can get is `<br/>.*<br/>`

Comment: You asked this yesterday and it was closed. There was a comment asking you what you have tried. Could you show us that? It's also hard to tell what you mean by selecting. Notepad++ regex doesn't "select" anything.

Comment: This question has just been deleted, why are you posting it again? Try rephrasing or posting what you have so far. SO isn't a code writing service

Comment: There was a link to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) when your question was deleted. Did you read that?

Comment: ya i read, that's y i ask here. im trying to ask something about regex n using notepad++ for my project. it should be okay rite?

Comment: Notepad++ questions will do fine here. It's just that your question is really vague. As I already asked you: what is "select" supposed to mean?

Comment: sorry about my poor english, im trying my best to describe my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by "select"? You can't just select it in Notepad++.

If you want to replace it, you can do a workaround like this

```
^(.*?<br/>.*?)<br/>
```

and replace with

```
\1Replacement
```

But this will not select the second occurence, it will select everything till the second occurence and then you need to replace also the part before the second occurrence using `\1`.

Important here is the anchor `^` it assures that the regex searches from the start of the row, the other important point are the lazy quantifiers `*?`, if you don't use them they will match to much and if there are 3 `<br/>` available also one of those, so that the regex match till the last occurrence of a `<br/>`.

Comment: you can "store" part of the match into backreferences. You do this by putting brackets around the part of the pattern you want to store. You can access those stores submatches then by using `\1` for the part in the first bracket, `\2` would access the second bracket and so on.